# Create new git branch: azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsClientRequestError: The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, python-requests, git-branch, azure-devops-rest-api

**Background:**

I'm using the [azure-devops-python-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) - library in order to programmatically [push a commit](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-git-push-command-explained) to my Azure DevOps [organization (git) repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/create-organization?view=azure-devops).

The [Azure DevOps REST API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-ref?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP) for "Update - Ref" did not help me to figure out the solution.
[This discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/259) did not help me either.

**Problem:**

"The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'" when calling `update_ref()` in module `azure\devops\released\git\git_client_base.py`.

There is no obvious function for creating a branch, which would be called `create_branch()` according to the [principle of least surprise](https://www.centercode.com/glossary/principle-of-least-surprise).
As opposed to this Azure DevOps API, this is much more intuitively resolved in e.g. the [AWS CodeCommit API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit/client/create_branch.html).

Anyways, I would like understand what exactly goes wrong here.
The error message is very generic, I could not determine which of the inputs are the problem.

Even when I provide the `filter` - argument instead of being `None` to the target or source branch name, it throws the following error:

> azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: The only property which can be patched is isLocked.

For the sake of completeness, the short docstring of filter from the above-mentioned module:

> :param str filter: The name of the branch to lock/unlock

I would also be greatful for any other way of simply creating a new branch which does not exist.

---

**Source Code:**

The code involved until invoking the `git_client.update_ref()` - method, is:

```
from azure.devops.v5_1.git.models import (
    GitRefUpdate,
)
from azure.devops.connection import Connection


release_head_commit_id = '12312314123123123213123123123'
project_name = 'project_x'
repo_name = 'project_x'
release_branch_name = 'target-branch'
feature_branch_name = 'feature-branch'
git_client = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials).clients.get_git_client()

filter_name = None  # or feature_branch_name or release_branch_name alternatively

git_client.update_ref(
                GitRefUpdate(
                    is_locked=False,
                    name=feature_branch_name,
                    new_object_id=release_head_commit_id,
                    old_object_id='0' * 40,
                    repository_id=repo_name,
                ),
                repo_name,
                filter_name ,
                project=project_name,
                project_id=project_name,
            )
```

The `old_object_id='0' * 40` was set like this based on [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/259#issuecomment-586061275).